# Closing react-bootstrap popup modal by passing function from parent component to child component via props not updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am unable to update the state of a parent react component by passing a parent function `this.togglePopup` to child component via props.

I can successfully open a bootstrap modal (react-bootstrap) by passing the parent's `this.state.open` to the child, but am unable to close the popup / update the parent component's state via the `this.togglePopup` function passed to the child.

The application was bootstrapped using `create-react-app`.

**public/index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Parent from './components/Parent';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent></Parent>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/components/Parent.js**

```
import React  from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        };
        this.togglePopup = this.togglePopup.bind(this);
    }

    togglePopup() {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.props.open
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <a onClick={this.togglePopup}>Open Modal</a>
                <Child show={this.state.open} parentAction={this.togglePopup}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

**src/components/Child.js (Popup Modal)**

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        show: props.show
      };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <>
          <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.parentAction}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.parentAction}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.props.parentAction}>
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </>
      );
    }
  }

export default Child;
```

Sure it's something simple I have missed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `togglePopup` you use value from props, that is always `undefined`. You should use `this.state.open`

```
togglePopup() {
    this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually for hooks you can just pass the setModal(true) as a props like this

```
 const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
 <AddUserModal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={modalClose}
        setModalShow={setModalShow}
      ></AddUserModal>
 {/* in the AddUserModal */}
   {/* get props */} { setModalShow } = props;
{/* persist it to the next Component as a function */} 
        <SignUp setModalShow={setModalShow} />
    {/*  consume it in SignUp as the function it is maybe after a network call */} 
setModalShow(false)
```

all in all you can pass the function as a prop